# How to see for which question I got a down vote

Tags: feature-request, down-votes

Today I saw a question with just phpphpphpphpphpphpphphphp and the answer content was just sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf. So I added a comment like "Moderators please delete this question".

After a while I got a downvote. THe reputation tab and the popup which appears when mouse is hovered on my name showed requtation -1. -1 had a link and when I clicked that the old reputations appeared and I couldn't find for which question I got down vote.

This happened in Stack Overflow. The reputation was 341 and not it is 340.

Actually after a few seconds the moderators closed that question and had deleted it.

?

Comment: Please, use the flag link rather than posting "Moderators please delete this"

Answer (score 3):

Probably you downvoted this question, which is deleted already because of spam flags.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562769/phpphpphpphpphpphpphpphpphpphpphpphpphpphpphpphp

only 10k+ users could see question now.

if you think, you should get -1 back, check your reps at https://stackoverflow.com/reputation

and there is recalc button, if you see your reps is 341 there, you could initiate the button to get 1 rep back.

Comment: I recalced and it went down to 337. But there won't be any more surprises.